# Variable storage in simulink

Tags: matlab, simulink

I am working on a simulink model, in which i am getting a supply of a a variable at certain time intervals and i need to use the recent 10 values of that variable only. 
how should i proceed with that?

Comment: Is that variable used as an input to your model or is it an output of the model (using the toWorkspace block)?

Answer (score 0):

It's a bit cheesy, but how about using a chain of Unit Delay blocks?

Comment: or simply a tapped delay (http://www.mathworks.com/help/toolbox/simulink/slref/tappeddelay.html )

Comment: yep, using the tapped delay block will be the easiest and fastest solution .